# What are opentok sub-domains roles

Tags: webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I am using opentok web SDK for webRTC video. 
When I look at the requests during a session, I see several sub-domains being approached, and I would like to know what's the role/purpose of them, specifically:
1. anvil.opentok.com
2. static.opentok.com
3. mantis.opentok.com
4. hlg.opentok.com

Anyone that has the knowledge I'd be happy if you could share.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

1. API server
2. JS source
3. Media server
4. Logging server